# How can I add a dot under Chinese characters and paragraph?

Tags: amsmath, ctex

I'm trying to practice TeX by typing my algebra textbook, but now I have a problem when adding dot under Chinese characters.
The picture shows where I encountered this problem.
[image]
I tried `\dot` in math mode and `\d` in text mode, but they don't work.

My code goes like this:

```latex
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst} 
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setcounter{page}{98}
\begin{document}
\[
\boldsymbol{\gamma}=\boldsymbol{\gamma}_0+\boldsymbol{\eta},
\]
\dot{其}中 $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ 是导出组 (1) 的一个解. 因此, 对于方程组 (9) 的任一个特解 $\gamma_0$, 当 $\boldsymbol{\eta}$ 取遍它的导 出组的全部解时, (10) 就给出 (9) 的全部解.
```

I got an error:

```
Package amsmath Error: \dot allowed only in math mode. \dot{其}
```

I need amsmath to show my math formula, how could I solve this problem?

Comment: Not a solution for the "underdot-problem" but probably worth mentioning anyway: If I got things right, you can use `\xeCJKsetup{CJKmath=true}` for having Chinese characters in math mode as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using xelatex, you can use `\CJKunderdot` of the `xeCJKfntef` package (documented with [`xeCJK`](https://ctan.org/pkg/xecjk)).

```
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{xeCJKfntef}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\setcounter{page}{98}
\begin{document}
\[
\symbf{\gamma}=\symbf{\gamma}_0+\symbf{\eta},
\]
\CJKunderdot{其中 $\symbf{\eta}$ 是导出组 (1) 的一个解. 因此, 对于方程组 (9) 的任一个特解 $\gamma_0$, 当 $\symbf{\eta}$ 取遍它的导 出组的全部解时, (10) 就给出 (9) 的全部解.}
\end{document}
```

[image: dots]

Note that I also loaded `unicode-math` and changed `\boldsymbol` to `\symbf` (I think this is recommended practice with unicode engines).